# Passing variables through the views, with express and pug

Tags: node.js, express, inheritance, model-view-controller, pug

My endpoint in the control is like this:

> **contoControl.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('../config/passportConfig');
var riepilogoService = require('../services/riepilogoService');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', passport.ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    riepilogoService.getUserData(req.user.id, (userData) => {
        res.render('conto', {title: 'Home', userData: userData});
    });
});
```

every time I load the 'conto' view, the userData variable is updated from db and sent to it, userData in the views is used like this and everything works perfectly:

> **conto.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
    body
        div.card-content
            ul.collection#listamovimenti(style='border-radius: 15px;')
                each movimento in userData.ultimiMovimenti
                    li.collection-item.avatar
                        if(movimento.importo > 0)
                            i.material-icons.circle.green(style='margin-top: 12px;')
                                | arrow_upward
                            span.title
                                | #{movimento.nomeMitt}
                            p
                                | #{movimento.descrizione}
                                br
                                | #{prettyDate(movimento.data)}
```

the 'conto' view extends layout and I would like to use the userData variable even in layout, for example to do the same thing I do inside 'conto', but the userData variable is not seen in layout

> **layout.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang='it')
    head
        ...
    body
        ...
        //the same thing I do with userData in the 'conto' views
        ...
        .container
        block content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think since there is no route defined for layout there would be nothing to pass and render.

To consider, unless you are intending to replace the `block content` on child pages with unique content then perhaps consider using `include`. Blocks as I understand aren't 'building blocks of code' per say but rather 'areas' or 'blocks' of replaceable content per view. eg inside a `block` you could have some unique code and an include with more code being pulled in, all inside a block so that on other pages you can edit the blocks contents more flexibly.

Answer (score 0):

i have nearly the same setup and it works in my project.

What happens when you insert this line in layout.pug, in the body?
p #{userData[0].ultimiMovimenti} or p #{userData[0].ultimiMovimenti[0]}